# CVS Diff to output only modified files?

Tags: linux, diff, cvs

Is it possible? Run a `cvs diff` in terminal at the project root that outputs only modified files (like local files that aren't in source control and local modified files - mainly what I did to my project).

I'm running `cvs diff --brief` but I still have too many results since my project is large, and with a lot of subdirectories - it shows the whole hierarchy and I just want to know which files are different from HEAD revision. I would like it to output one line per file - I'm going to merge using VimDiff.

I'm using Linux btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cvs diff` only reports files that have changes by default, and you can turn off the noise about directories with the `-q` option to `cvs` (i.e., `cvs -q diff`; it works for all subcommands). If `--brief` is still producing too much output, you've probably just let your sandbox drift too far! (Dump to a file and stick it in an editor. Or pipe to a paging utility that can go backwards, like `less`.)